# Maven failsafe plugin not executing tests

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

For debugging purposes I tried including all tests and still failsafe is only picking up one test (ChangePriorityTest). All tests are being compiled successfully in the correct target directory.

`pom.xml`

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>at.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>citest</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <name>citest</name>
    <description>Test project to improve our CI pipeline</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>all-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unit-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
                <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Unit test report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Directory structure:

```
- src
|- test
|-- java
|--- at/test/citest
|----   domain/model/todo
|-----    ChangePriorityTest
|----   interfaces/rest/todo
|-----    TodoRestDocumentation
|---- TestIntegrationTest
```

I tried downgrading the version, including all tests via `**/*`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it possible to convert the screenshot of text back to plain text, and include the relevant parts of your pom here instead of links to some random site?

Comment: it looks ok. Does your TestIntegrationTest contain a test? with a @Test annotation? You do not need the plugins within the dependencies section, the build/plugins section is enough. Does the failsafe plugin run at all? (check the logs) You did no activate a profile?

Comment: Yes the failsafe plugin runs but only executes the `ChangePriorityTest`.`TestIntegrationTest` is a sampe integration test from spring annotated with `@RunWith` And `@SpringBootTest` and contains one test method annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: Why do you declare `surefire` and `failsafe` in your `<dependency>` section? Are you really using their classes in your code?

Comment: Have you seen [`<skipTests>`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#Optional_Parameters): "Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion. Failsafe plugin deprecated the parameter `skipTests` and the parameter will be removed in _Failsafe 3.0.0_ as it is a source of conflicts between Failsafe and Surefire plugin."?

Comment: Ha! A Wiener! Habe die Ehre! :)

Comment: I put them in the dependency section because I wanted to have all project dependencies and their versions, regardless if its a plugin or project dependency, in one place, whereas their configuration in another. Thanks for the hint, this might explain why the surefire tests are still exexuted on my CI server altough specifing this property.

Comment: _A plugin is not a dependency_ in terms of Maven. The "one" place(s) for centralized dependency/plugin config (`<version>` and everything else) are `<dependencyManagement>` and `<pluginManagement>`. Often used is a [`<properties>` section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) for centralized version declaration: `<properties><junit-jupiter-api.version>5.5.2</junit-jupiter-api.version></properties> ... <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId><version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using JUnit 4 instead of 5 and replacing the two JUnit 5 dependencies (junit-jupiter-engine and junit-jupiter-api) with JUnit 4.

Still don't know what the problem was ...